# Error while creating SessionFactory object form hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i am creating a HibernateUtil.java class to return SessionFactory Object. but it's giving Error "The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class". my code is as --

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you didn't include jre system liberary in build path.

```
Right click on project --> Properties --> select Java Build Path --> Libraries -->    
Add Library --> JRE System Library --> Next --> Workspace default JRE --> Finish
```